# Large numbers of input files causing program to not function at all

Tags: c

I'm working on a word frequency program that is designed to handle any number of input files. It works fine for smaller numbers of files, even if those files have tens of thousands of words, but when attempting to run it with a larger number of files (24 in the case I'm testing), it barely even begins reading from the first file before segfaulting.

```
typedef struct {
   int noInFiles, numFiles, numToPrint;
   char** fileNames;
   FILE** files;
   Hash hash;
} Freq;

void openFiles(Freq* freq) {
  int i;
  char* str;

  freq->files = calloc(1,sizeof(FILE**));

  for(i = 0; i < freq-> numFiles; i++) {
  freq->files[i] = fopen(freq->fileNames[i],"r");
  if(freq->files[i] == NULL) {
         str = malloc(strlen(freq->fileNames[i]) + 5);
         sprintf(str,"wf: %s",freq->fileNames[i]);
         perror(str);
         free(str);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   }
}

void wordCount(Freq* freq) {
   int i, totalWords = 0;
   char *word = NULL;
   unsigned wordLength = 0, memSize = 0;

   for(i = 0; i < freq->numFiles; i++) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Counting from file %d named %s\n", i,freq->fileNames[i]);
      while(EOF != getWord(&word, &wordLength, &memSize, freq->files[i], "file"))
      {
         addEntry(&(freq->hash), word, 1);
         totalWords++;
         free(word);
         word = NULL;
      }

   }
   freq->totalWords = totalWords;
}
```

Valgrind says that openFiles has an `Invalid write of size 4` but i have no idea what that means

Comment: Perhaps closing the files when done would help along with checking that you have successfully opened the file in the first place

Comment: Closing the file wouldn't matter since the code currently doesn't even get to the point where I could close anything. And the if statement in openFiles is there exactly for insuring that the file is in fact opened

Comment: You are not using `calloc` correctly, see my change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
freq->files = calloc(1,sizeof(FILE**));
```

According to the sturct, you will need a `FILE*` to each of the files, but this line just allocate one `FILE**`, change to this:

```
freq->files = calloc(freq->numFiles, sizeof(FILE*));
```

Comment: That did it! I previously allocated things differently, and changed that at the suggestion of a friend of mine. Interesting that it didn't matter until I got to larger file numbers though